# How can I stop Advanced REST Client standalone on MacOS from constantly opening new windows?

Tags: advanced-rest-client

While ARC is open, its icon in present in the MacOS dock, as expected.  However, every time I click this icon while ARC is not in focus, rather than simply focusing ARC, it opens an entire new window. How can I stop this annoying behavior?

Answer (score 0):

There was a bug, which is already fixed. (https://github.com/advanced-rest-client/arc-electron/issues/70)

You should upgrade to the latest version.